# Firefox warn on exit

Tags: firefox

Seems like this has been impossible in Firefox for quite some time. Anyone knows if there is an update that enables a workaround or if Firefox is planning to fix this?

To be clear: what I need is a dialog that asks for confirmation when closing the window, either using Ctrl+W, Alt+F4, or using clicking the X of last tab or window. This is regardless of how many tabs are contained in the window.